# Supercomputers have millions of CPUs or cores. Is there a central chip or CPU that controls all the cores?

Tags: cpu

What device integrates and coordinates all the data from millions of CPUs/cores in a supercomputer? To call these cores CPUs (Central Processing Unit) seems wrong when they are not central at all but comprised of millions of units. Isn't there one processing unit or device that is truly at the center? I have Googled this question but no one has a good answer. Even Wikipedia has no info on this.

Comment: Why would supercomputers be uniform in this regard?